# Use Stored procedure like a function 

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I need to deal with the table name as a variable.Then I must using dynamic sql and therefore I must using Stored procedure.
But the problem that how can I use the stored procedure like a custom sql function.

e.g: select col1,(Exec sp1 param1,'tbName') from table1

Comment: You can't. 

The only way of using a stored procedure in an at all similar way is using a loop backed connection but then you would need to use dynamic SQL to pass the parameter to the stored procedure leaving you no better off!

Comment: You don't "need" at all: perhaps you should give us the bigger picture so we can offer solutions...

Comment: OP said: `I need to deal with the table name as a variable`, I say: this is most likely the result of a design problem.  you can use your plyers as a hammer, it may work a little, but that isn't what they were designed to do.  Use the hammer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally,I changed my design and and use dynamic SQL in one upper level.

Answer (score 0):

This will be posible in sql server denali that introduces the new keywords "WITH RESULTSET".

The alternative on current sql versions is passing a temp-table to the stored procedure

Comment: I believe it's the scalar result, not the result set, that the OP is after. They have to use an SP, because they need to pass a table name as a parameter, and that implies dynamic scripting, which in turn implies that a function cannot be used (otherwise this question wouldn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures can return scalar values through output parameters. Here's an example (from [here](http://vstoolsforum.com/blogs/sqlserver/archive/2007/04/20/creating-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters.aspx)).

Create the stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE _4P_test 
    @intInput INT,
    @intOutput INT OUTPUT
AS
    SET @intOutput = @intInput + 1
```

Call it like this:

```
DECLARE @intResult INT

EXEC _4P_test 3, @intResult OUT

SELECT @intResult
```

However you should try to design your system so that you don't have to use dynamic SQL in the way you described.